# Scroll to a div within a div on certain action

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to scroll to a particular div automatically when called upon in JavaScript/jQuery?

I can use `$('div[compid="' + compid + '"]')` to get the correct div but I need to force the div with that particular compid to be scrolled to on the screen.

```
$(document).delegate(".heading",'click',function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');
});
```

```
<div id="listings">
    <div class="heading" compid="80" usedspec="33"><div class="content">content in here</div></div>
    <div class="heading" compid="81" usedspec="34"><div class="content">content in here</div></div>
    <div class="heading" compid="82" usedspec="35"><div class="content">content in here</div></div>
    <div class="heading" compid="83" usedspec="36"><div class="content">content in here</div></div>
    <div class="heading" compid="84" usedspec="37"><div class="content">content in here</div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `offset` method.

```
var top = $('div[compid="' + compid + '"]').offset().top;
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: top}, 500);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aNBMG/

Please note that `compid` and `usedspec` are not valid attributes, you can use HTML5 `data-*` attribute instead.